# String coupled to Kalb-Ramond field under gauge transformation

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, string-theory, gauge-theory

I'm studying how a string coupled to a Kalb-Ramond 2-form $B_{\mu \nu}$ is affected by a gauge transformation of the K-R field, $\delta B_{\mu \nu} = \partial_{\mu} C_{\nu} -  \partial_{\nu} C_{\mu}$ from David Tong's [notes](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string.html), chapter 7, pages 190-191. I cannot work out the last step in the following: $$ S_{B} = \frac{1}{4 \pi \alpha'} \int_{\mathcal{M}} d\sigma  d\tau \epsilon^{\alpha \beta}\partial_{\alpha} X^{\mu} \partial_{\beta} X^{\nu} B_{\mu \nu} \rightarrow S_{B} + \frac{1}{2 \pi \alpha'} \int_{\mathcal{M}}   d\tau d\sigma \epsilon^{\alpha \beta} \partial_{\alpha} X^{\mu} \partial_{\beta} X^{\nu} \partial_{\mu} C_{\nu}$$ $$ = S_{B} +  \frac{1}{2 \pi \alpha'}\int_{\mathcal{M}} d\tau d\sigma \epsilon^{\alpha \beta} \partial_{\alpha} (\partial_{\beta}X^{\nu}C_{\nu}). $$ Here, $\alpha, \beta $ run over $D$-brane coordinates $\sigma, \tau$ and $\mu,\nu$ run over spacetime. I have tried integrating by parts and am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Hint: Try work backwards from the last expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the fact that
$$
\varepsilon^{\alpha\beta}\partial_{\alpha}\partial_{\beta}=0
$$
and the chain rule
$$
\partial_{\alpha}=\partial_{\alpha}x^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\,.
$$

Comment: Got it, thank you. I was hesitant to use $\partial_{\alpha} x^{\mu} = \delta^{\mu}_{\alpha}$ because I wasn’t sure that two of the spacetime directions would coincide with the world sheet directions.

Comment: $\partial_{\alpha}x^{\mu}\neq \delta_{\alpha}^{\mu}$ in general. Note that depending in the Dp-brane dimension this might not even agree in terms of number of indices. It is also not reparametrization invariant. In fact you can use it for $p+1$ of your $x$'s to fix reparametrization invariance. I did not use it here

Comment: Right, got it. I misinterpreted the chain rule to assume the presence of a Kronecker delta. The chain rule is true irrespective of what gauge you use.

Comment: Just used that $(\partial_{\alpha}x^{\mu})\partial_{\mu} C=\partial_{\alpha}C$.